# Finding N shortest paths in a graph

Tags: python, networkx

I need to find the `N` shortest path between two nodes.
As example, the following code create three nodes and four edges, and the two shortest paths are `(1, 3) and (1, 2, 3)`

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, **{'weight': 15, 'max': 3})
G.add_edge(1, 3, **{'weight': 30, 'max': 4})
G.add_edge(2, 3, **{'weight': 20, 'max': 3})
G.add_edge(2, 3, **{'weight': 20, 'max': 5})
```

Is there a method in NetworkX to find them?

I'm aware of the method `nx.all_shortest_paths(rete,1, 3, weight='weight')`, but in cases like this one the method returns only *the* shortest path, (1,3).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like you can generate all simple paths between two vertices starting from the shortest paths with `shortest_simple_paths`:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#

### Edit: answer for multigraphs

This is a very crude solution to get the answer you're looking for. I assume it will only work well for small graphs:

```py
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, **{'weight': 15, 'max': 3})
G.add_edge(1, 3, **{'weight': 30, 'max': 4})
G.add_edge(2, 3, **{'weight': 20, 'max': 3})
G.add_edge(2, 3, **{'weight': 20, 'max': 5})

# get all paths and convert them to tuples so that we can
# deduplicate them
paths = [tuple(p) for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 1, 3)]

# sort the paths according to the number of nodes in the path
print(sorted(set(paths), key=lambda x:len(x)))
```

### Edit 2: answer for weighted multigraphs

This is a bit more complicated, you need to write your own "path score" function and pass it to the sorter.

```py
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, **{'weight': 15, 'max': 3})
G.add_edge(1, 3, **{'weight': 30, 'max': 4})
G.add_edge(2, 3, **{'weight': 20, 'max': 3})
G.add_edge(2, 3, **{'weight': 20, 'max': 5})


def get_edge_weight(u, v):
    """Return the minimum weight of all edges between nodes u and v."""
    return min([e['weight'] for e in G.get_edge_data(u, v).values()])


def weighted_path_score(path):
    """Sum of edge weights in path."""
    edges = zip(path, path[1:])
    return sum(get_edge_weight(u, v) for u, v in edges)


paths = [tuple(p) for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 1, 3)]

# sort using the weighted path score
print(sorted(set(paths), key=weighted_path_score))
```

You can play around with edge weights and check that the order of returned paths respects it (e.g. setting a high weight to edge 1-3 will result in the path `(1,2,3)` being listed first).

Comment: Thank you, but this raise a `NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for multigraph type`

Comment: You could also use `all_simple_paths` which will return all paths and then sort them using your own logic. Note that because it's a multigraph, you'll get the path `(1, 2, 3)` twice in your result.

Comment: As last piece: how to take the `weights` in account?